# Get object thymelaf

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a `for:each` like this:

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="bill : ${bills}" id="bill">
        <td th:text="${bill.bill_id}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.client.phone}"></td>
        <td th:text="${bill.date}"></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" 
    id="open-modal">Ver detalles</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The question is how can I get the entire `${bill}` to a variable in JavaScript or jQuery because I need more information. I saw the documentation and it said:

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
   /*<![CDATA[*/
   ...

    var user  name = /*[[${bill}]]*/ '';

    ...
   /*]]>*/
 </script>
```

I have tried this on a external JavaScript file and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Thymeleaf 3, this should be enough

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    var user  name = [[${bill}]];
</script>
```

And you have to put it in `.html` file because by default it process `.html` file. You can add it in your `.html` file and it will be available in the scripts included after the above code in the `.html` file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "data" attribute in your HTML:

```
<td th-data:id="${bill.id}" th-data:name="${bill.nome}" class="js-datas">
```

And in your javascript, then you can get:

```
var id = $('.js-datas').data('id');
var nome = $('.js-datas').data('name');
```

You have to use the follow namespace in your HTML:

```
xmlns:data="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/data"
```